# Cannot disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

Tags: systemd, services, mint

I ran a command

> sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service

to disable the service, but after reboot I still see it in the output of `systemd-analyze blame`. Also `status NetworkManager-wait-online.service` returns

```
● NetworkManager-wait-online.service - Network Manager Wait Online
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-01-01 11:25:48 PST; 44min ago
     Docs: man:nm-online(1)
 Main PID: 1620 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: I don't need to disable network service permanently, just on start up.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable this? Are you trying to solve a slow boot up time, or something else? I believe disabling this will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: yes, it takes 8 seconds during boot, so I want to disable it since all files are local and there is no need for internet connection during start

Comment: What version of mint are you using? I had this irk with long boot times with 18.3, they tidied up the boot times for Network manager nicely in 19.1. Personally I wouldn't play around with disabling Network manager on boot, likely to cause issues. But i suspect this is still doable